# Why a method containing "this" can't be passed in as an array methods inside another method

Tags: javascript

I can understand that A doesn't work because I'm calling from outside, but why doens't B work? I thought when a method is calling another method, `this` refers to the object?

```js
const foo = {
  bar: 'bar',
  sayBar() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  },
  sayBar3times() {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(this.sayBar);
  },
};

/* test A */ [1, 2, 3].forEach(foo.sayBar); // doesn't work
/* test B */ foo.sayBar3times(); // doesn't work either
```

I can understand

Comment: Because you didn't `.bind` it.

Comment: welcome to the rabbit hole; [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/get-started/ch1.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you do `[].forEach(this.sayBar)`, the `this` actually refers to the windows object. When you invoke `this.sayBar` using an arrow function, then you pass on the lexical this (which is the object itself) to the function.

> Note: If passing the callback function uses an arrow function expression, the thisArg parameter can be omitted, since all arrow functions lexically bind the this value.
>
> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Using_thisArg)

For this very reason, that is why `Array.prototype.forEach` accepts `thisArg` as the second positional argument, so you can do `[].forEach(this.sayBar, this)` and it will work:

```js
const foo = {
  bar: 'bar',

  sayBar() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  },

  sayBar3times() {
    // this doesn't work:
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(this.sayBar);
    
    // this works:
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(this.sayBar, this);
    
    // this works:
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(() => {
      this.sayBar();
    });
  },
};

foo.sayBar3times();
```

With regards to your updated code, the answer is the same:

- Test A does not bind the `foo` in the callback, so `this` refers to the global object `window`. This can be fixed by simply doing `[1, 2, 3].forEach(foo.sayBar, foo)`. In this case, the `this` inside the method call will now refer to the `foo` object.
- Test B does work because the `sayBar3times` lacks binding context in the `forEach()` as well. So, if you provide `thisArg` correctly, by doing `[1, 2, 3].forEach(this.sayBar, this)` it will work

In both examples, you will need to provide a `thisArg` to the callback in `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
const foo = {
  bar: 'bar',
  sayBar() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  },
  sayBar3times() {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(this.sayBar, this);
  },
};

/* test A */
[1, 2, 3].forEach(foo.sayBar); // doesn't work
[1, 2, 3].forEach(foo.sayBar, foo); // works

/* test B */
foo.sayBar3times(); // works
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I'll mark it as correct soon. I slightly changed the wording of my question to reflect my thinking, please feel free if you'd like to edit the answer one more time. Thanks!

Comment: @Quuxuu Updated my answer with your new code.

Answer (score 0):

You should research the usage of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) in JavaScript:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach((this.sayBar).bind(this))
```